# why am I losing content when I convert a file from .ps to .svg

Tags: svg, icons, sprite, ps, psd

I need icons for a site I'm having developed, and therefore I need .svg files.  I have a .psd file that I `save as` a .ps file.  I then attempt to use cloudconvert.org to convert the .ps file to .svg.  The problem is that it fails to capture the whole image -- only leaving about 40% of the original.  What can I do??

Comment: use illustrator instead!

Comment: @RachelGallen unfortunately I don't use either.  I paid a freelancer and he did the work in PS.

Comment: you can download a trial vsn of illustrator for free for 30 days form the adobe website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the Adobe suite, you can use Photoshop to File - > Export-> Paths to Illustrator, 
save as a .ai file and then save it as an svg from illustrator without losing quality.

Hope this helps

EDIT: you can download [a trial version of illustrator](https://creative.adobe.com/products/illustrator) for free for 30 days form the adobe website

Comment: When I "Export" as Paths to Illustrator and open *in* illustrator, I see nothing -- literally a blank AI canvas inside the screen -- yet I believe that I am following the steps perfectly.  Any thoughts?  Does that problem sound familiar or is it more likely something specific to my setup/process?  Thanks for any assistance.